# Getting data from a View back to the controller using ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I have a class with members like this:

```
[NotMapped]
public string Description { get; set; }
[NotMapped]
public bool Available { get; set; }
```

and I show them in the view like this:

```
<td>
    <div class="col-md-12">
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Description, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
    </div>
</td>
<td>
    <div class="col-md-12">
        @Html.CheckBoxFor(model => model.Available, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Available, new { @class = "control-label"})
    </div>
</td>
<td>
    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
            <input type="button" id="GoButton" value="Apply" class="btn btn-default" />
        </div>
    </div>
</td>
```

Attached to the button is a script that makes an ajax call to the controller like this.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$("#GoButton").click(
    function() {
        $.ajax(
            {
                url: '@Url.Action("DoSomething", "SomeController")',
                type: 'POST',
                dataType: 'json',
                data:
                {
                    description: $('select[name="Description"]').text(),
                    avail: $('select[name="Available"]').val()

                }
            }
```

And the signature of the function in the controller is:

```
public ActionResult DoSomething(string description, bool avail)
```

This all works except the value of 'description' and 'avail' in DoSomething() are always "" and false no mater what is happening to those items on the view. Their true values don't seem to be making it over to the controller.

What am I doing wrong?

[ANSWER]

My entire problem was with the way I was coding the `data:` section of the script. This is the correct code for that section.

```
description: $('#Description').val(),
avail: $('#Available').is(':checked')
```

Comment: Is there any particular reason you aren't wrapping this in a form and using the built-in Ajax helpers with MVC? Otherwise it looks like your jquery selectors are wrong - should be $("#Description").val() and something like $("#Available:checked").length== 0 ? false : true

Comment: Thank you for addressing the Description.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

'CheckBoxFor' doesn't render 'select' but 'input'

instead of

```
description: $('select[name="Description"]').text(),
avail: $('select[name="Available"]').val()
```

try

```
description: $('input[name="Description"]').val(),
avail: $('input[name="Available"]').is(':checked')
```

Comment: The code that actually worked was `avail: $('#Available').is(':checked')`

Comment: CheckBoxFor will render "id" and "name" with same value. It's up to you what you want to choose. It will work in both cases.